# Kafka-console-consumer not consuming data from producer

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

Kafka Version : **kafka_2.11-0.11.0.1**

when I try to send messages from producer to consumer in a **Multi-node Kafka Ecosystem,** the message is getting sent, and broadcasted from Kafka server! These messages can be read by using Kafka Consumer via  Zookeeper [which is going to be deprecated on following version!], and also via `kafka-simple-consumer-shell.sh`

```
./bin/kafka-simple-consumer-shell.sh --broker-list <broker-ip>:9092  --topic myTopic
```

But cannot be read from Consumer via consumer-bootstrap-server!

**Call to Consumer via Zookeeper-server :**

```
./bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic myTopic --zookeeper <broker-ip>:2181 --from-beginning
```

**Call to Consumer via Bootstrap-server :**

```
./kafka-console-consumer.sh --topic myTopic --bootstrap-server <broker-ip>:9092 --consumer.config ../config/consumer.properties
```

My `config/producer.properties` contains:

> bootstrap.servers= {broker-ip}:9092
>
> compression.type=none

My `config/consumer.properties` contains(nothing):

> # zookeeper.connect={private-ip-1}:2181,{private-ip-2}:2181
>
> # timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
>
> # zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
>
> #consumer group id
>
> group.id=test-consumer-group
>
> #consumer timeout
>
> # consumer.timeout.ms=7000
>
> # consumer.timeout.ms=-1

My `config/server.properties` contains:

> listeners=PLAINTEXT://{private-ip-1}:9092
>
> advertised.host.name={private-ip-1}
>
> advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://{private-ip-1}:9092
>
> advertised.port=9092
>
> host.name={private-ip-1}
>
> zookeeper.connect={private-ip-1}:2181

Comment: Try to add `auto.offset.reset=smallest` in consumer.properties and retry.

Comment: :( @amethystic,  no positive responce

Comment: What about appending `--from-beginning` to the command? Seems `auto.offset.reset` will be overwritten by the code due a known bug.

Comment: i had read it sin some stackpost! and from there i am trying with it! still no messages are retrived

Comment: it may be related to advertised.listeners. is that private ip reachable from your consumer? If you try the same exact sentence on the broker with localhost:9092 and does consume, then that's it. Also, set listeners to 0.0.0.0:9092